# How can I know my rating in chess

Tags: rating

I play chess **sometimes**.
I don't know any chess strategy. I just know the direction of each piece.
How can I know my rating?

Comment: Then you don't have a rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't **one** rating. Each site or chess federation would rate you differently. Even if two different organizations use the exact same rating system, the separate pools of players make the numbers incomparable. You can find your rating *for a certain organization* by playing enough games for the statistics to become meaningful.

What's this about statistics? Ratings are approximations of our playing strength.  Rating systems are based upon opponents' ratings and use statistics to predict the outcome of games. The results of games are used to adjust ratings. The more we play, the more accurate the ratings become.

I don't know where you're located, but in the USA, you'd likely be rated about 800. An average club player is about 1500. The 700 point difference would mean you'd have virtually no chance of defeating someone who had a poor chance of defeating that average player.

Comment: 800 seems like it's pulled out of a hat.  It could just as easily be 200, from the given description.  800 is very weak compared to a club player, but someone at that level does know more than just how to move the pieces.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not play in tournaments, then you do not have a rating. You are **unrated**.

If you play online, then you will have a rating. However, this is **unofficial** and cannot be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you understand the tules of the game, playing on a chess based website such as Chess.com will give you an approximation of your rating. That would be a good starting point, although in general a beginner would start at around 1200 elo. (In chess, we measure one's rating in elo)

Comment: beginners start at 100 in USCF.  The real question is how beginner is a beginner.

Comment: "*In chess, we measure one's rating in elo.*" Not everywhere. Also, it's Elo, with a capital "E", as it is named for its [inventor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpad_Elo).

Answer (score -1):

your rating is 100 but only because they dont go lower

start reading some books to improve

play over grandmaster games to get a feel for what good moves look like in an opening

work through tactical problem collections to learn to recognise patterns of winning moves

to get a provisional rating play in rated events

to get an established rating play in lots of events

Comment: again some coward downvoted a correct answer without saying why.

Comment: @edwinaoliver: The downvote wasn't mine, but last time I tried to leave an explanation for a downvote I got a pop up saying such practice is discouraged - a 180 from how SE once operated. Also, this isn't a "correct answer"; an unrated player is simply unrated, not 100. Furthermore, without knowing the player's federation you don't know what the minimum rating would be - while I believe the Brits are changing their system, in the past a 100 rating in England was considered decent for a club player.